# React-native, react-native-router-flux && Custom Icon on Drawer NOT working

Tags: javascript, react-native, customization, drawer, react-native-router-flux

Until now it renders but ***doesn't*** open the drawer.

I believe is something associated to the references but I'm not sure.

if someone could help me it will be awesome.

**router.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Actions, Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux';

import Dashboard from './components/dashboard';
import Home from './components/home';
import ViewCamera from './components/view-camera';
import Register from './components/register';
import SideDrawer from './components/sideDrawer';
import TabIcon from './components/tabIcon';

function openDrawer() {
  return (<TabIcon
    press={() => {
      Actions.refresh({ key: 'drawer', open: true })
    }}
  />);
}

class RouterComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene key="root">
          <Scene
            panHandlers={null}
            key="home"
            hideNavBar component={Home} title="Login" initial
          />
          <Scene
            panHandlers={null}
            key="viewCamera"
            hideNavBar component={ViewCamera} title="Captura del Documento"
          />
          <Scene
            panHandlers={null}
            key="register"
            hideNavBar component={Register} title="Registro"
          />
        </Scene>
        <Scene
          key="drawer" component={SideDrawer}
        >
          <Scene
            key="tabs"
            tabs
          >
            <Scene
              initial
              panHandlers={null}
              component={Dashboard}
              hideTabBar
              key="dashboard"
              title="Propuestas"
              renderLeftButton={openDrawer}
            />
            {/*<Scene panHandlers={null} key="pollCreation" component={Poll} />*/}
          </Scene>
        </Scene>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default RouterComponent;
```

**components/tabIcon.js**

```
import React, {
  Component,
  PropTypes,
  StyleSheet
} from 'react';

import {
  Text,
} from 'react-native';

import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import { Button } from 'native-base';
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const propTypes = {
  selected: PropTypes.bool,
  title: PropTypes.string,
};

class TabIcon extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        transparent
        onPress={this.openDrawer.bind(this)} style={styles.navButton}
        style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' }}
      >
        <Text>
          <MaterialIcons name="menu" size={30} />
        </Text>
      </Button>
    );
  }
  openDrawer = () => {
    Actions.get('drawer').ref.toggle();
  };
}
TabIcon.propTypes = propTypes;

const styles = {
  navButton: {
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    flex: 1,
  }
};

export default TabIcon;
```

**sideDrawer.js**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';

import {
  BackAndroid,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';
import { Drawer } from 'native-base';

import { DefaultRenderer, Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
import SideBar from './sidebar';

const propTypes = {
  navigationState: PropTypes.object,
};

class SideDrawer extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    closeDrawer: React.PropTypes.func,
    drawerState: React.PropTypes.string,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      animatingLoadingSpinner: false,
      url: 'polls',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
      Actions.pollCreation();
    });
    Actions.refresh({ key: 'drawer', ref: this.refs.navigation });
  }

  finishSpinnerAnimation() {
    this.setState({
      animatingLoadingSpinner: false
    });
  }

  startSpinnerAnimation() {
    this.setState({
      animatingLoadingSpinner: true
    });
  }


  noServerConnection() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.errorBody} >
        <Text > No es posible la conexión con Nuestros servidores </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const state = this.props.navigationState;
    const children = state.children;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} >
        <Drawer
          ref='navigation'
          type="overlay"
          tweenDuration={150}
          content={
            <SideBar
              closeDrawer={() => {
                this.drawer.close();
               }}
            />
          }
          tapToClose
          acceptPan={false}
          openDrawerOffset={0.2}
          panCloseMask={0.2}
          styles={{
            drawer: {
              shadowColor: '#000000',
              shadowOpacity: 0.8,
              shadowRadius: 3,
            },
          }}
          tweenHandler={(ratio) => {  // eslint-disable-line
            return {
              drawer: { shadowRadius: ratio < 0.2 ? ratio * 5 * 5 : 5 },
              main: {
                opacity: (2 - ratio) / 2,
              },
            };
          }}
          negotiatePan
          onOpen={() => Actions.refresh({ key: state.key, open: true })}
          onClose={() => Actions.refresh({ key: state.key, open: false })}
        >

          {/*<View style={{ marginTop: 45 }} />*/}
          <DefaultRenderer navigationState={children[0]} onNavigate={this.props.onNavigate} />
        </Drawer>
      </View>
    );
  }

}

let WEBVIEW_REF = 'webview';
const BGWASH = '#F6F6F6';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: BGWASH,
  },
  addressBarRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 10,
  },
  errorBody: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  navButton: {
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    flex: 1,
  },
  navText: {
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  navTextContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    flex: 8,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

SideDrawer.propTypes = propTypes;
export default SideDrawer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was base myself on [nativebase](http://nativebase.io/) and on its [example](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink) .

1. Add Redux

   [image: Actions && Reducers]

   **drawerActions.js**

   ```
   import type { Action } from './types';

   const OPEN_DRAWER = 'open_drawer';
   const CLOSE_DRAWER = 'close_drawer';

   export function openDrawer():Action {
     return {
       type: OPEN_DRAWER,
     };
   }

   export function closeDrawer():Action {
     return {
       type: CLOSE_DRAWER,
     };
   }
   ```

**drawerReducer.js**

```
import type { Action } from '../actions/types';

export const OPEN_DRAWER = 'open_drawer';
export const CLOSE_DRAWER = 'close_drawer';

export type State = {
    drawerState: string,
    drawerDisabled: boolean
}

const initialState = {
  drawerState: 'closed',
  drawerDisabled: true,
};

export default function (state:State = initialState, action:Action): State {
  if (action.type === OPEN_DRAWER) {
    return {
      ...state,
      drawerState: 'opened',
    };
  }

  if (action.type === CLOSE_DRAWER) {
    return {
      ...state,
      drawerState: 'closed',
    };
  }

  return state;
}
```

1. Using react-redux I connected the *sideDrawer.js* component
        import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
       import { connect } from 'react-redux';

   ```
   import {
     BackAndroid,
     StyleSheet,
     Text,
     View,
   } from 'react-native';
   import { Drawer } from 'native-base';

   import { DefaultRenderer, Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
   import SideBar from './sidebar';
   import { closeDrawer } from '../actions';

   const propTypes = {
     navigationState: PropTypes.object,
   };

   class SideDrawer extends Component {
     static propTypes = {
       closeDrawer: React.PropTypes.func,
       drawerState: React.PropTypes.string,
     }

     constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
         animatingLoadingSpinner: false,
         url: 'polls',
       };
     }

     componentDidMount() {
       BackAndroid.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', () => {
         Actions.pollCreation();
       });
       Actions.refresh({ key: 'drawer', ref: this.refs.navigation });
     }

     componentDidUpdate() {
       if (this.props.drawerState === 'opened') {
         this.openDrawer();
       }

       if (this.props.drawerState === 'closed') {
         this.refs.navigation.close();
       }
     }

     openDrawer() {
       this.refs.navigation.open();
     }

     closeDrawer() {
       console.log(`onClose: ${this.props.drawerState}`);

       if (this.props.drawerState === 'opened') {
         this.props.closeDrawer();
       }
     }

     finishSpinnerAnimation() {
       this.setState({
         animatingLoadingSpinner: false
       });
     }

     startSpinnerAnimation() {
       this.setState({
         animatingLoadingSpinner: true
       });
     }


     noServerConnection() {
       return (
         <View style={styles.errorBody} >
           <Text > No es posible la conexión con Nuestros servidores </Text>
         </View>
       );
     }

     render() {
       const state = this.props.navigationState;
       const children = state.children;
       return (
         <View style={styles.container} >
           <Drawer
             ref='navigation'
             type="overlay"
             tweenDuration={150}
             content={
               <SideBar
                 closeDrawer={() => this.closeDrawer()}
               />
             }
             tapToClose
             acceptPan={false}
             openDrawerOffset={0.2}
             panCloseMask={0.2}
             styles={{
               drawer: {
                 shadowColor: '#000000',
                 shadowOpacity: 0.8,
                 shadowRadius: 3,
               },
             }}
             tweenHandler={(ratio) => {  // eslint-disable-line
               return {
                 drawer: { shadowRadius: ratio < 0.2 ? ratio * 5 * 5 : 5 },
                 main: {
                   opacity: (2 - ratio) / 2,
                 },
               };
             }}
             negotiatePan
             onCloseStart={this.closeDrawer.bind(this)}
           >
             <DefaultRenderer navigationState={children[0]} onNavigate={this.props.onNavigate} />
           </Drawer>
         </View>
       );
     }

   }

   const BGWASH = '#F6F6F6';

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({
     container: {
       flex: 1,
       backgroundColor: BGWASH,
     },
     addressBarRow: {
       flexDirection: 'row',
       height: 10,
     },
     errorBody: {
       alignItems: 'center',
       justifyContent: 'center',
     },
     navButton: {
       alignItems: 'flex-end',
       flex: 1,
     },
     navText: {
       fontSize: 18,
     },
     navTextContainer: {
       alignItems: 'center',
       flex: 8,
       justifyContent: 'center',
     },
   });

   SideDrawer.propTypes = propTypes;
   const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
     const { url } = state.polls;
     const drawerState = state.drawer.drawerState;
     return { drawerState, url };
   };
   const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
     closeDrawer: () => dispatch(closeDrawer()),
   });

   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SideDrawer);
   ```
2. Connect the *tabIcon.js* also, it will be in charge to open the drawer when tap.

   ```
   import React, {
     Component,
     PropTypes,
     StyleSheet
   } from 'react';

   import {
     Text,
   } from 'react-native';

   import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
   import { Button } from 'native-base';
   import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
   import { connect } from 'react-redux';
   import { openDrawer } from '../actions';

   const propTypes = {
     selected: PropTypes.bool,
     title: PropTypes.string,
   };

   class TabIcon extends Component {
     openDrawer = () => {
       this.props.openDrawer();
       // Actions.refresh({ key: 'drawer', open: value => !value });
     };
     render() {
       return (
         <Button
           transparent
           onPress={this.openDrawer.bind(this)} style={styles.navButton}
           style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' }}
         >
           <Text>
             <MaterialIcons name="menu" size={30} />
           </Text>
         </Button>
       );
     }
   }
   TabIcon.propTypes = propTypes;

   const styles = {
     navButton: {
       alignItems: 'flex-end',
       flex: 1,
     }
   };

   export default connect(null, { openDrawer })(TabIcon);
   ```